# Chef: How to display nodes IP Address

Tags: chef-infra

1. I've noticed that there are 2 commands that can be used to display nodes. However, it only display the hostname and not the IP Address.
   Please let me know if there's a way to display IP Addresses on each of these nodes.
2. What are the differences between `knife node list` and `knife client list` commands? The outputs are looks alike.

**knife node list**

```
C:\chef\cookbooks>knife node list
cheftestnode1
cheftestnode2
cheftestnode3
C:\chef\cookbooks>
```

**knife client list**

```
C:\chef\cookbooks>knife client list
admin-validator
cheftestnode1
cheftestnode2
cheftestnode3
C:\chef\cookbooks>
```

I would like to see the output in the IP Address format instead of hostname like this. Is this possible?

```
C:\chef\cookbooks>knife node list
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3
C:\chef\cookbooks>
```

or like this. Would it be possible?

```
C:\chef\cookbooks>knife node list
cheftestnode1 - 10.1.1.1
cheftestnode2 - 10.1.1.2
cheftestnode3 - 10.1.1.3
C:\chef\cookbooks>
```

Answer (score 6):

The simplest option is to use `knife exec`:

```
knife exec -E 'nodes.all.each {|n| puts n["ipaddress"] }'
```

Answer (score 1):

That could be done quiet easily using a tool which Chef provides which is ***ohai***. So if you type ohai on your command line you would be able to see / grep for the host IP address as well as other attributes.

The answer to your second question would be as follows:

Node = Machine

Client = User that authenticates against chef-server

The ***Node*** will run your recipes
The ***Client*** has the permission level to access your chef server

So it would be something like:

When your host would try to connect to your chef server it will say Hello I am Client X, could I have the run list for node Y?

Answer (score 1):

To answer question #2 if you want to retrieve the IP of a Chef node do the following

`knife node show <your node name> -a ipaddress`

To see a full list of all the information you can return with the -a flag do the following

`knife node show <your node name> -l`

If you want to retrieve all the IPs for a set of nodes then construct a list of them and iterate over it in a loop. One example of grabbing every ip address and outputting to console:

`knife node list > node_list.txt
while read p; do eval "knife node show ${p} -a ipaddress"; done < node_list.txt;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use search option with some filter to limit the output and parse the json output with jq:

knife search node "Environment:prod*"  -F json | jq -r '.rows[]|"|(.name)|(.automatic.ipaddress)|"'